# How to send session variables from old PHP plain system to Symfony3 app

Tags: php, symfony

I have a very old plain PHP system.

I need to take a session variable from old system and use it in Symfony3.

On example I have plain PHP with fallowing session:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['surname'] = 'test';
echo var_dump($_SESSION);
```

And Now I need to take it in Symfony controller:

```
public function offerAction(Request $request)
{

    // some code

    echo var_dump($_SESSION);
    // or:
    $session->get('name');

    // some code
```

How Can I do this?

At the moment I am not interested in security issues - 
this is a test solution and ultimately everything will be done according to the best practices :)

Comment: just pass $_SESSION to the function?

Comment: What is the problem with your example code? And have you started the session?

Comment: In Symfony3 session is started, the point is that I have two completely different sessions. I guess it's a security issue

Comment: You've to use `$this->get('session')->get('surname')` inside your controller.

Comment: This is not right solution. I have two completely different sessions so for me $this->get('session')->get('surname') is empty.

Answer (score -1):

I also had similar project with legacy session. So what I did. I've created the request listener where I read the legacy session and copy values from it to Symfony's session. Something like that:

```
$legacySessionFile = '/path/to/session/file'
$rawSessionData = @file_get_contents($legacySessionFile);
if ($rawSessionData) {
    try {
        session_start();
        session_decode($rawSessionData);
        $legacySession = $_SESSION;
        session_abort();
        if (!empty($legacySession)
            && !empty($legacySession['surname'])
        ) {
            $this->symfonySession->set('surname', $legacySession['surname']);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->debug(sprintf('Error reading session data. Exception %s: "%s" at %s line %s',
            \get_class($e), $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine()));
        throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('Unauthorized');
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an awful lot wrong with the code above. Not least that the session Id is not resolved.

Comment: Old session ID is the file name. If we already have the session which has been created by the legacy application what are the ways to read them? Manually, that's what I suggest. And this works.

Comment: So did thalidomide.